# Delete the action of a button event and make another event

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons that draw a graph.
The first one draws a graph with some values and the second one draws a graphic with other values.Both graphs are drawn in the same location on my HTML page.
The problem is that the graphs overwrites if i press the both buttons 
consecutively and i don't refresh the page.

```
$("#buttonA").click(function(){
deseneazaGrafic(jsonData.Antena3);
});
```

and the second button

```
$("#buttonP").click(function(){
deseneazaGrafic(jsonData.ProTV);
});
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why not block the button to Ajax has been finished?

Comment: I'm new to web delevoping. Can you please show me? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I might need to see deseneazaGrafic() to properly answer.

My first thought would be to blank out the element where the graph is drawn.  lets say it is a div with id graphdiv that gets filled with the graph.

then inside both button click events before the call to deseneazaGrafic()

make this call:

```
$("#graphdiv ").empty();
```

see here for more http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: what do you mean by overwrites in the description of the problem?

Comment: i mean, when i press the first button, the graph is drawn. But when i press the second button , the second graph is drawn over the first one.

Comment: Yes, this will happen always because you have just one canvas and the graph will overwrite the previous, this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/73wsfhx8/2/

Comment: $("#buttonA").click(function(){
$("#canvas").empty();
deseneazaGrafic(jsonData.Antena3);
});

$("#buttonP").click(function(){
$("canvas").empty();
deseneazaGrafic(jsonData.ProTV);

}) i tried this way. Doesn't work

Comment: Is there any way to put the second graph in the first graph's place? and delete the first one?

Comment: the .empty() method sounds nice, but it doesn't work

Comment: Or when i click on the  second button, the first canvas goes hidden and then appears the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
 I need to clear the graph before it is drawn in "deseneazaGrafic"(translate:drawGraph) function
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)